# Express TypeError object is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-2.0

I keep getting this error saying TypeError: getVowels.find is not a function.
This is a swagger Express project learning how to create a mongoose function to find. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var VowelsSchema = require('../models/vowels');

// connect to our database
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');

module.exports = router;

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var getVowels = new VowelsSchema();      

  getVowels.find(function(err, vowels) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(vowels);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly using `find` method. It doesn't work on `instance of your model`, but it works on the `model` itself.

So instead of `getVowel.find(function(err,vowels){...})` , try this

```
VowelsSchema.find({},function(err,vowels){//its always a good practice to ue {} in find
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(vowels);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `VowelsSchema` is a Mongoose Model, the [`Model.find()` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) is defined on the constructor itself:

```
VowelsSchema.find(function (err, vowels) { ... });
```

Rather than as a method of the instance, `getVowels`.

---

Note: Mongoose's [API documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) uses 2 "operators" to distinguish the types of methods:

- Periods (`.`) for constructor methods – e.g. [`Model.count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count)

  ```
  ModelType.count(function ...);
  ```
- Number signs (`#`) for instance methods – e.g. [`Model#save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)

  ```
  var instance = new ModelType({ ... });
  instance.save(function ...);
  ```